# Is there anything like "isEmpty" for text field in ruby watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Sample Code:

```
<td id="frm.measurementUnit_fe" align="left" colspan="1">
 <select id="frm.measurementUnit" size="1" name="frm.measurementUnit">
  <option selected="true" value=""> - Please Select - </option>
  <option value="9">Application</option>
  <option value="5">IU</option>
  <option value="11">Puffs</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

I need to check whether this field has a selected value or not before save the form. 
Since `.text == ""` is not working here.

Is there anything like java `isEmpty()` here?

Any one please help....

Answer (score 1):

You are working with a [select list](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select) rather than a text field.

You can get the select list's selected value by using the `value` method. For example:

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'frm.measurementUnit').value
```

Therefore you can check if there is a selected value by comparing the value to `''`:

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'frm.measurementUnit').value == ''
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use followin approach:

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'frm.measurementUnit').selected_values.included_in?([9,5,11]) #you can verify if all selected values in select list contains following values in value attribute
```